# How to check if property exists in array stored in a variable in PHP

Tags: php

I have 7 dynamic fields and about to get the values. Instead of checking the fields one by one, I have created an array and stored it in a variable and used loop. The current data uses object and not sure on how to check if those fields are existing.

Here's a sample object code:-

```
$data->field_name_field_1 = 1;
$data->field_name_field_2 = 2;
$data->field_name_field_3 = 3;
$data->field_name_field_4 = 4;
$data->field_name_field_5 = 5;
$data->field_name_field_6 = 6;
$data->field_name_field_7 = 7;
```

Here's a sample code with loop-

```
$fields = array('field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3', 'field_4', 'field_5', 'field_6', 'field_7');
foreach ($fields as $field) {
  if (!isset($data->{"field_name_$field"})) {
    continue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using an array instead of numerated fields?

Comment: It was designed that way.

Comment: so much easier: `$data->field_name_field=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);`

Comment: Then the design is stupid. Fix it. Doing two stupid things in a row will not make it one smart thing.

Comment: Can't change it as it was rendered by the current system and I was just fetching the data.

Comment: What is the issue with your code? I can't find any error. It seems working.

Comment: @AnkitSingh It returns an empty value even though it really has a value.

Comment: <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined property: stdData::$field_name_ in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>34</b><br />

Comment: There's nothing wrong that I can see with the code you've posted. It just doesn't actually *do* anything, since all you've got is an empty loop. If you add in some basic output, it works fine: https://eval.in/1003106